# Multiple users access singleton

Tags: sql, multithreading, locking, singleton

I'm using a SQLconnector singleton class with a lock object. My question now is that if multiple users use this class the same time, will this give issues?

FYI... Singleton code

```
public sealed class SqlConnector
{
   private static volatile SqlConnector instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   public static SqlConnector Instance
   {
     get
     {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
               if (instance == null)
               {
                  instance = new SqlConnector();
               }
            }
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }

   public Execute(...)
   {
     //what ever
   }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea, as we don't know what's *in* the singleton. I would point out that there are cleaner approaches to implementing the singleton pattern in the first place though. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: I want to execute commands, stored procedures, ... on an sql database

Comment: That really doesn't tell us much about whether or not the class is inherently safe to use from multiple threads. For example, if you create a new `SqlConnection` in each method, it may well be - but if you're trying to reuse a connection, you'd need to be more careful.

Comment: ah ok, so my thread-safe singleton doesn't have anything to do with multiple users than?

Comment: It does, in that singletons should be implemented in a thread-safe way. But you haven't shown anything about what your class actually does, so we can't tell whether it *is* thread-safe.

Comment: ok, thanks, than I'll keep working on it

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very good practice to use a SqlConnector as a Singleton.
The connection Pooling will handle it for you.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx :

> To deploy high-performance applications, you must use connection
>   pooling. When you use the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server,
>   you do not have to enable connection pooling because the provider
>   manages this automatically, although you can modify some settings. For
>   more information, see SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET).

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Class SqlConnector should be thread-safe

Comment: instance members are not thread-safe : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx (see Thread Safety section)